# Blur and sticker view together in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, blur, sticker

I'm trying to create a blur effect in such a way that when a shape (square, rectangle, circle) is selected. The shape is applied as a sticker on the image showing in the ImageView and the image got blurred but the inside of the shape should show the original image and not the blur image. Also the shape should be free to move, resize and rotate.

https://github.com/adnaanaeem/MultiShapeBlurView
I have tried this library but it only apply few shapes also they are static and not freely moving or resizing.